# fetching json data from local file

Tags: json, reactjs

TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function
Trying to access local json data.
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './index.css'

```
   class App extends Component {
     constructor(){
        super() 
        this.state = {
         data: []
         }

       }
     componentDidMount()
      {
        fetch("./employeeData.json")
       .then(res => res.json()) 
       .then(daabta => {
        this.setState({data: daabta })
        } )
       }
     render() {
       return (
         <table>
          <tbody>{this.state.data.map((item, index) => 
            <tr key = {index}>
              <td>{item.userId}</td>
              <td>{item.firstName}</td>
              <td>{item.lastName}</td>
              <td>{item.region}</td>
             </tr>
            )      
           })}</tbody>
         </table>
        )
       }
      }
     export default App;
```

Comment: Please describe your problem and what you try to achieve. So far you only gave us there error and the code (good start).

Answer (score 2):

You can just import your json file directly at the top of your component like

```
import * as employeeData from "./employeeData.json";
```

but be careful your json data would be inside and object named `default` so when you want to access the data you should use `employeeData.default`